# Getting a response from a wsh script

Tags: jscript, wsh, hta

In my HTA app there are some actions which are executing some heavily time-consuming tasks on a server. For example an action uses an old ActiveX component to read some fileproperties (like Subject and Comments) of files in a particular folder (0 - ~200 files in a folder).

Originally this was done by setting an interval, and reading the fileproperties file by file. The slowing down of the app was acceptable when connected to the server using fast local connections. But now, as remote working has significantly increased, and the remote connections are magnitudes slower than the intranet connections, the interval is not suitable for the task anymore.

To make the app faster during the filepropety search, I outsourced the code to a wsh job. The results are stored in a file, which of existence an interval (5 secs) is observing. However, some users are still experiencing remarkable slow-down of the app, even when polling the file existence with the said interval of 5 secs.

Now I wanted to know, if there is an event or some other internal mechanism, which I could use to detect when the wsh script has done its job? And if possible, even perhaps there's a way to send the results directly from the wsh job to HTA, without using the intermediate temporal file at all?

Here's some simplified code for the actual task performed in the wsh file and HTA app. HTA has the HTML5 DTD and it's running in Edge-mode using IE11. `ui` is an utility library, the referred propertynames are hopefully describing the usage accurate enough.

WSF:

```xml
<package>
<job id="getFileProps">
<script language="JScript">
    (function () {
        var topRoot = WScript.Arguments(0),                           // The starting folder <String>
            fso = WScript.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'), // Filesystem object <ActiveXObject>
            fileProps = readProps(topRoot),                           // Fileprops, the result <Array>
            file;                                                     // The result file to read in HTA <FileObject>

        function readProps (root) {
            var fileProperties = [];
            // A bunch of code reading the fileproperties on a disk
            return fileProperties;
        }

        file = fso.openTextFile(topRoot + '\\$fileprops$.txt', 2, true);
        file.Write(fileProps.join(',');
        file.Close();
        WScript.Quit();
    )());
</script>
</job>
</package>
```

JSCRIPT:

```js
ui.winShell.Exec('WScript //Job:getFileProps ' + '"' + ui.appRoot + '"');
function fpCheck () {
        var file, fileProps;
        try {
                file = ui.fileIO.OpenTextFile('$fileprops$.txt', 1, false);
        } catch (err) {
                file && file.Close();
                setTimeout(fpCheck, 5000);
                return;
        }
        // Write the fileprops to the view
}
```

If someone is interested in the fileproperty reader, its name is `DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties`. It originates somewhere to the deep internet archives, but I can't recall where I've loaded it from.

Comment: Users complaining about slowness because the data file on a remote share?
If so, instead remote data file why don't you poll a `local` file that will be initially created by WSH Job and deleted when the process is complete? I am sure this will be pretty fast.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Yes, the result file is saved in a remote folder, but only for a part of users (I actually didn't realize to check whether the complainers were using a shared copy from the server or their own local copy). Sounds reasonable to create it as local, I'll definitely try that. Thanks for a suggestion.

Comment: Bah ... Some users had re-installed the old version. But still I'd like to know, if there's a way to get a message from wsh when it's done its job, or pass the list of the properties directly to HTA without using the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually what you need is Inter-Process Communication.

Neither HTA or WSH do offer something built-in for IPC.

So, I'm going share a hacky solution that I rarely use.

The trick is to use a shared object in the two ends like a client-server scenario.

We're going to use and Internet Explorer object as an IPC server, the methods we will use are [GetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752088(v=vs.85)) and [PutProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752095(v=vs.85)).

Since Internet Explorer windows can be enumerated by using [Shell objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell)'s [Windows()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-windows) method, it's possible to access the object created in HTA from another application.

Examine and create the following two files, then start `test.hta` and click `Start WSF` button.

`test.hta`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <title>IPC</title>
        <script>
            sharedObject = {
                sendData: function(data){
                    // blocking here is not a good idea 
                    // so we process the data within another callback
                    // leaving the method as soon as possible
                    var receivedData = data;
                    setTimeout(function(){alert("Data received: " + receivedData)}, 50);
                }
            };
            
            shareName = "ipcShare";
            serverId = createIPCServer(shareName);
            
            function createIPCServer(shareName){
                var ie = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
                ie.PutProperty(shareName, sharedObject);
                window.onbeforeunload = function(){ ie.Quit(); };                
                return ie.HWND; // window handle
            }
            
            function starWSFJob() {
                alert("please wait about 5 seconds...");
                var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
                wshShell.Run('wscript.exe test.wsf //Job:TestIPC /serverId:"' + serverId + '" /shareName:"' + shareName + '"');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="starWSFJob()">Start WSF</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

`test.wsf`:

```html
<package>
    <job id="TestIPC">
        <script language="JScript">
            function getSharedObject(serverId, shareName){
                var shellApp = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
                var windows = new Enumerator(shellApp.Windows());
                for (;!windows.atEnd();windows.moveNext()){
                    var window = windows.item();
                    if(window.HWND == serverId) {
                        return window.GetProperty(shareName);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            function App() {
                var serverId = Number(WScript.Arguments.Named("serverId"));
                var shareName = WScript.Arguments.Named("shareName");
                var sharedObject = getSharedObject(serverId, shareName);
                if(!sharedObject){
                    WScript.Echo("shared object not found.");
                    return 1;
                }
                
                // simulate long running job
                WScript.Sleep(5000);
                
                // send data
                sharedObject.sendData("Hello from WSF Job!");
                
                return 0;
            }

            WScript.Quit(App());
        </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

Comment: Wow! You've really been working on this. Maybe it's a bit complex, but this is what I asked for. I'll test it tomorrow, and tick your answer, if anything simpler won't occur. I've used an IE instance to apply ES5 in a WSH script, but I've never thought it could be used this way too.

Comment: @Teemu Nothing is simple when it comes to IPC :) But you can make sure that this is one of the simplest IPC implementations you can do in Windows. 
Because there are horrible out-of-process COM marshaling operations being done behind the scenes and we don't have to deal with any of them and it is a bless.

Comment: True. I couldn't actually get your script to work for me (as WScript.Sleep can't be used in HTA), and I chose a bit different approach to speed up the property reading. But, your snippet gave me a ton of ideas which I can utilize in some other tasks, thank you very much for the snippet.

Comment: @Teemu My bad. Never hit that line on my tests, apparently my computer was fast enough. The `Navigate` call and the loop were not even required, so I deleted them.

Comment: As I couldn't run an IE instance (yet), what do you think, would it be possible to run a task with that IE instance, without a WSH? I assume I could pass even live object as arguments to the script in the IE instance, and the script would resolve some tasks using even direct references to JS objects in HTA?

Comment: @Teemu I'd say yes but Internet Explorer's security models is like a minefield so I'd stick with the WSH for sure. Ability to direct reference to HTA objects is also apply in WSH depending on which object you share.

Answer (score 0):

Would your scenario support use of a dictionary object or array list to store just filename and lastupdated, and to only retrieve the full properties set (into a second list) for new or changed files (and deletes). Depends on how frequently the files are coming and going or being updated I would guess. This could be quicker than generating the entire file properties dataset if most of the details are not changing between polls.

Comment: It's a custom file browser with a foldertree and filelist. The filelist shows filename and Subject only. The filenames are fetched and shown quickly, but `DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties` operation is somewhat slow, and that's why it's called asynchronously after the filenames are shown. Polling the resulting file seems to slow down the app for some reason for some users, probably Kul-Tigin has spot on it (I haven't checked that yet, though).